# What is the "positive question record"?

Tags: support, questions, reputation

What is the positive question record in figure below?
[image]

Comment: It is defined e.g. [in this meta.SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/263383)

Comment: See [Asking days badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges). This includes a definition for the positive question record.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was answered in the comments, but to make it more formal: the documentation for this and all badges is in the help centre and in the cross-network [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com); in this case in [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges). Quoting from there,

> - **positive question record**
>
>   ```
>   (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)
>                                                   /total questions >= 0.5
>   ```
>
>   It *triple counts* a question that is downvoted, closed, and
>     deleted. If you ask one that hits that trifecta, you'll need to ask
>     three better questions to dig yourself out.

And just to emphasise again, the [mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is the first place to check for these things.