# Answer posted with extremely little potential for acceptance

Tags: discussion, answers, post-ban

Does an accepted edit to a question allow the subsequent withdrawal of an earlier answer (which had been posted to it) to be accomplished without any resulting potential for limiting or reducing the answerer's ability to post further answers? (If I would've read the biographical info offered by the questioner, I would not have bothered to post an answer almost certain to endure forever--for reasons of conscience-- without their acceptance, but the reading of biographies is hardly what the site is about.)  I'm aware that answers with a zero score can be a factor in an answer ban, which would render the entire site virtually useless to me.

Comment: Your question is worded in a way that makes it hard to read (for me at least). Just to make sure I understand, are you asking if answer deletion doesn't count towards a ban if the question was edited since posting the answer?

Comment: What kind of edit? [Chameleonised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)?

Comment: I think I initially misunderstood this question, and I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are worried about an answer ban, you should not delete answers. See e.g. [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8851/44126) or [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24803/166791) (although those define an positive contribution record for questions, rather than answers).

If the question is been edited in a way that invalidates existing answers, that's bad form. Usually the community's response is to revert the meaning-changing edit and engage in a dialog with the editor --- sometimes in the comments, and sometimes escalating to Meta. If you're involved in such a discussion and it's not going well, you can summon the diamond moderators by flagging the post.