# What to do with a horrible question haunting my question record?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, best-practices, deleted-questions

The third question I posted to this site was, in retrospect, awful. I deleted it after an hour of it being posted and learned to pose better questions since.

Anyway, I’ve become aware that a deleted question haunts a person’s question score permanently. I’m concerned that there’s no way to fix it without it being a weird variant of much older answered questions regarding the tachyon antitelephone.

So, should I just not bother and move on, or is there a good strategy to salvage an early mistake like this? Link to question posed below (but only mods can see it, since it’s still deleted).

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/777498/

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber deleted questions still persist in actual logs, so admins can look them up. Their impact on the total rep will also stay.

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber The relevant search term is [positive question record](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8851/44126).

Comment: For what it's worth, the question is visible not just to moderators; for example, I can see it. I think the requirement is sufficient rep.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just continue to participate in the site in a constructive way, and don't worry about one deleted question.

If your early participation includes *lots* of downvoted/closed/deleted questions, you may encounter some limits on how frequently you post. Those limits are not punitive: their purpose is to encourage users to *think* about how our community works and how their participation can mesh nicely with it. If you are already thinking about those things (which your thoughtful post here demonstrates), you are unlikely to need that automated feedback.